# reshape panel data from long to long, but expanding variables

Tags: r, reshape

I have large dataset in long format, with multiple variables 'stacked', a structure similar to

```
set.seed(42)
dat_0=data.frame(
  c(rep('AFG',4),rep('UK',4)),
  c(rep('GDP',2),rep('pop',2)),
  rep(c('1990','1991'),4),
  runif(8))
colnames(dat_0)<-c('country','variable','year','val')
```

which produces the following

```
  country variable year          val
1     AFG      GDP 1990 0.0856120649
2     AFG      GDP 1991 0.3052183695
3     AFG      pop 1990 0.6674265147
4     AFG      pop 1991 0.0002388966
5      UK      GDP 1990 0.2085699569
6      UK      GDP 1991 0.9330341273
7      UK      pop 1990 0.9256447486
8      UK      pop 1991 0.7340943010
```

I want to have each variable (GDP, pop) in one column

```
  country year        GDP       pop
1     AFG 1990 0.0856120649 0.6674265147
2     AFG 1991 0.3052183695 0.0002388966
3      UK 1990 0.2085699569 0.9256447486
4      UK 1991 0.9330341273 0.7340943010
```

I am really sorry if this is a duplicate, but after going through earlier posts I have still not managed to re-structure my data.

Comment: use `spread` `library(tidyr);spread(dat_0, variable, val)`

Comment: even though `tidyr` is preferred nowadays, you can still use `dcast` from `reshape2`. `dat_0 %>% 
  dcast(country+year~variable, value.var = "val")`